# Decoding date storage in legacy database aka "fun" with numbers

Tags: database, binary, reverse-engineering

I'm writing a utility to rip records out of a legacy DB(that we can't query), and I'm having trouble interpreting how a date field is stored.

All Dates will be in MM/DD/YYYY format. Hex will be bytes(2 digits) separated by spaces.

What we know:

1. Hours and mins are stored in a different location. Adding an hour or min to
   the datetime does not effect the 4 bytes in question
2. The field that corresponds to the Month, day and year is 4 bytes:

   - 01/01/1800 == 70 8E 00 00
   - 01/15/1800 == 7E 8E 00 00
   - 01/16/1800 == 7F 8E 00 00
   - 01/31/1800 == 8E 8E 00 00
   - 02/01/1800 == 8F 8E 00 00
   - 02/02/1800 == 90 8E 00 00
   - 02/15/1800 == 9D 8E 00 00
   - 02/16/1800 == 9E 8E 00 00
   - 02/28/1800 == AA 8E 00 00
   - 02/29/1800 == AB 8E 00 00 #PLACEHOLDER FOR LEAP YEAR
   - 03/01/1800 == AC 8E 00 00
   - 12/01/1800 == BF 8F 00 00
   - 12/02/1800 == C0 8F 00 00
   - 12/03/1800 == C1 8F 00 00
   - 12/15/1800 == CD 8F 00 00
   - 12/16/1800 == CE 8F 00 00
   - 12/30/1800 == DC 8F 00 00
   - 12/31/1800 == DD 8F 00 00
   - 01/01/1801 == DE 8F 00 00
   - 12/31/1801 == 4A 91 00 00

Anyone have any ideas? And yes, I'm familiar with epoch time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 bytes. Each new day increments the byte farthest to the left. Once that byte gets to "FF" it adds 1 to the byte to the right of it. Try this.. (Written in Ruby)

```
 def parse_date(hex)
   actual_known_date = "1/1/2050".to_date
   known_date = "21F30100"
   total_days_since_known_date = 0

   first_byte = hex[0,2]
   second_byte = hex[2,2]
   third_byte = hex[4,2]
   fourth_byte = hex[6,2]

   known_first_byte = known_date[0,2]
   known_second_byte = known_date[2,2]
   known_third_byte = known_date[4,2]
   known_fourth_byte = known_date[6,2]

   byte_4_days = known_fourth_byte.hex - fourth_byte.hex
   byte_3_days = 0
   byte_2_days = 0
   byte_1_days = 0

   if known_third_byte.hex >= third_byte.hex
     byte_3_days = known_third_byte.hex - third_byte.hex
   else
     byte_4_days -= 1
     ktb = known_third_byte.hex + 256
     byte_3_days = ktb - third_byte.hex
   end

   if known_second_byte.hex >= second_byte.hex
     byte_2_days = known_second_byte.hex - second_byte.hex
   else
     byte_3_days -= 1
     ktb = known_second_byte.hex + 256
     byte_2_days = ktb - second_byte.hex
   end

   if known_first_byte.hex >= first_byte.hex
     byte_1_days = known_first_byte.hex - first_byte.hex
   else
     byte_2_days -= 1
     ktb = known_first_byte.hex + 256
     byte_1_days = ktb - first_byte.hex
   end

   total_days_since_known_date = (byte_1_days + (byte_2_days * 256) + (byte_3_days * (256 * 256)) + (byte_4_days * (256 * 256 * 256)))

   number_of_leap_days = 0
   date_we_want = actual_known_date - (total_days_since_known_date).days
   return date_we_want
 end
```